# Closest div with specific class

Tags: javascript, closest, toggleclass

I'm have a script working which toggles one div with another when you click the question. But it is targeting every div with that class. Is there a way to target the closest div so only the relevant answer toggles when I click a question?

```
<a class="faqquestion">The question goes here so it does?</a>  
<p class="answer1">This is the answer and Im an absolute GENIUS!!!! This is the answer and Im an absolute GENIUS!!!! This is the answer and. This is the answer and Im an.....</p>  
<p class="answer2 hidden">uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.<br /><br />  


uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.
</p>  


<a class="faqquestion">The question goes here so it does?</a>  
<p class="answer1">This is the answer and Im an absolute GENIUS!!!! This is the answer and Im an absolute GENIUS!!!! This is the answer and. This is the answer and Im an.....</p>  
<p class="answer2 hidden">uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu. uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.<br /><br />  


uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.uyigfiau faewiugfiaw ef iawugfi uwa fiwafiu wgaifbwaifg iuwagfiuawebfiu gwaiefgiuwagfuiaw gifgaiwfg iuaw gfiuwaifg iuawgfiuawgiufagwiug afwigu.
</p>  


<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".faqquestion").click(function () {  
      $('p.answer2').toggleClass('hidden');  
      $('p.answer1').toggleClass('hidden')  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual html and javascript you are having problems with?

Comment: .hidden is just display:none in css

Comment: There is a "code" button that you can use to format code correctly in your question. I've done this for you above but thought I'd let you know how for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're not actually using links there's no real reason to use `<a>`.  You can use divs, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="faqquestion">Question One?</div>  
<div class="answer1">Answer one</div>  
<div class="answer2 hidden">Answer two</div>

<div class="faqquestion">Question Two?</div>  
<div class="answer1">Answer one</div>  
<div class="answer2 hidden">Answer two</div>

<div class="faqquestion">Question Three?</div>  
<div class="answer1">Answer one</div>  
<div class="answer2 hidden">Answer two</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("div.faqquestion").click(function () {
        $(this).next("div.answer1").toggle().next("div.answer2").toggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: works for me with no div. thanks man, really appreciate the time! :)

Comment: @Moppy: It was IE that was behaving strangely without the `div`.  I've updated my answer to a div-specific one with a code sample, but if it ain't broke then don't fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

if i could give a answer in jQuery you can go to the closest via next() function in jQuery.

so you will have to look for jQuery("elementSel").next("div");

in simple javascript you will have to look for dom traversal methods a glimspe of your html can help find a exact answer.